# Is re-sanding needed after primer is applied to wood cabinets?

Tags: sanding

Just wondering if I should re-sand the primer I just applied to wood kitchen cabinets, BEFORE I apply the cabinet paint I purchased?  The kind of final coat I bought is Valspar latex with oil-enriched enamel (cleans up with water). It's supposed to be some sort of acrylic hybrid paint - alkyd or something like that. So because I've never used this paint before, I don't know what to expect. The Valspar cabinet paint can reads that it is not necessary to prime before painting...but because I had to sand these cabinet doors down to the bare wood practically, I thought priming was a better idea....so I primed them with a "bonding" primer, that I was told would work with the Valspar paint.  My question is this - now that they are primed...should I RE-SAND all the cabinet doors again before I apply the final coat?  Also...is there any tricks to making sure I get all the dust off before I apply the final coat?

Answer (score 3):

> should I RE-SAND all the cabinet doors again before I apply the final
> coat?

I would. As cabinet doors they will be quite visible and I'm sure you want the best finish possible.  A light sanding after the primer ensures that the primer is smooth which will help you get a good finish coat.

> Also...is there any tricks to making sure I get all the dust off
> before I apply the final coat?

"tack cloth"

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help.  I'm glad I asked.

Comment: I'd use a very fine sandpaper, like 280 grit. +1